# Why am I getting error: Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to int

Tags: entries

We just created an entry and hit save.  When we go to the front end of site we get a popup error that reads:

> Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to
>   int

What does this mean and how do I troubleshoot it

Comment: The `ElementCriteriaModel` is an object that prepares your queries. For example if you do `craft.entries` you'll receive an `ElementCriteriaModel` where you can insert ids, sections, relations and so on until you finally fetch all entries with the `find()` function. When you have a relation field attached to the entry the values of these are objects of type `ElementCriteriaModel` too, so you have a ready to use query that can be executed. It's likely you'll receive this error because you are trying to treat it as an integer in your templates. Do you have a relation field in your entry?

Comment: Thanks for super fast response! I don't think so, but can't tell.  Can I tell by looking at the entry fields when creating a page?  If so, then I see plain text fields, image fields, text sections that have wysiwyg fields.<br/><br/> If it is looking into the templates then I'm not sure what to look for there.  I do see some for loops etc, but I don't see something that 'relates' one entry to another entry or entry type.

Comment: Image fields are relation fields. Your image is nothing but an element and the field contains a query (lazy loading) when you do `entry.image` you have an `ElementCriteriaModel` so please update your answer with your template where you use your image. Many people think `entry.image` will return the images that are used in the entry but thats totally wrong.

Comment: I'm learning markdown so bear with me here... I pasted the template into a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/vurokurayi/edit?html,output

Comment: Next time please insert the code here at stack exchange in your question and format it a little bit so people can read it. I guess your error is in this line `gridImages.length != 1` it should be `gridImages|length` by the way - as I said gridImages is an object of type `ElementCriteriaModel` and no array. With the `|length` filter you execute the query and count the results. Doing `set count = gridImages|length` is a little bit better performance wise because you save the number once.

Comment: I made the gridImages.length fix and the page loaded fine.  I now see your next comment and don't understand how to fix the block.next() issue.  Are you willing to share a fix or edit the jsbin I linked to?  I will also format templates / code inside here at SE in future.. I appreciate your patience with me as a noob.

Comment: No no please forget about that. It was my mistake. I didn't realize you made a check with `loop.last` that's why I deleted my comment. Sorry for the confusion. I'm glad I could help you. Just one last hint: some of your if condition will always become true, no matter what. For example `if gridImages` you don't need all those checks because they'll all contain objects, not arrays. With `if gridImages` you check if gridImages is not null (it's always an object) with `for image in gridImages` you'll receive null (no image) or an array of images

Comment: How do I mark your comment as the best answer?

Comment: You can't mark comments, that's why I collected the information from my comments and created an answer, you can mark that as accepted so others will know the problem is solved. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) is an object that prepares your queries. For example when you do `craft.entries` you'll receive an `ElementCriteriaModel` where you can insert ids, sections, relations and many other attributes until you finally [fetch](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#fetching-the-elements) your entries with `find()`, `first()` or `ids()`.

When you have a relation field attached to the entry the values of these fields are objects of type `ElementCriteriaModel` too, so you have a ready to use query that can be executed.

This class has an `iterator` interface, that means the method `find()` is executed when you loop through it, that being said `for image in entry.images` does actually `for image in entry.images.find()`. Thus many people think `entry.images` contains an array of elements rather than one single element.

So - for future reference - when you ever receive an error like

> Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to XXX

It's likely you treated your `ElementCriteriaModel` as an array or element or string or whatever the error explains.

In your special case it was just a syntax error: change `gridImages.length` to `gridImages|length`